# How to use System.Speech in Unity?

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine

I want to use System.Speech to implement a text-to-speech to my unity desktop application. I don't get how to implement the System.Speech. When I type `using System.Speech;` in my C# file, it gives error : The type or namespace name `System.Speech` could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have copy the `System.Speech.dll` from `C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0` to the asset folder, but it doesn't work.

When I add it using Nuget, it says that it doesn't compatible with any framework.

Can someone explain how to add the reference, to make it works?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that `Unityscript` is a JavaScript-like language that was deprecated in 2018.  And the `Visual-Studio` tag should only be used when your question is *about* VS.

Comment: I don't think you can use that particular assembly in a Unity project.  I'm not sure how you would go about integrating speech services into your application, though

Answer (score 0):

you cant use this assembly directly in Unity, you have to have a wrapper

you could find a solution [Wrapper For unity](https://chadweisshaar.com/blog/2015/07/02/microsoft-speech-for-unity/)